# How to Mount freebsd-ufs USB Correctly to Transfer Files from One FreeBSD 12.1 computer to Another with 13.1

Tags: usb, freebsd, ufs

My Second Post. The First One Led to This Present One.

I am moving from FreeBSD 12.1 on one computer to FreeBSD 13.1 on another computer. All of my desired files are placed in one directory.

This is a simple job with nothing fancy; all that I want to do is copy one directory with subdirectories containing files onto the USB from the old system and then copy the same from the USB after I have created the new system.

The procedure followed below was done on the FreeBSD-12.1-RELEASE version. I cannot do anything on the 13.1-RELEASE until I copy my files from the former because the former is what is being replaced by the latter.

1. I bought a PNY 256-GB 3.0 USB Backward-Compatible USB.
2. INITIALISATION.
   I attached the USB to the computer.

/: cd dev

/dev: gpart show

// The new USB drive appears as da1. In the past, such drives have usually appeared as da0.

/dev: gpart destroy -F dev/da0

/dev: gpart create -s mbr dev/da0

/dev: gpart create -s gpt da1

/dev: gpart add -t freebsd-ufs da1

// This command creates da1/p1.

/dev: newfs -U /da1p1

// This takes several minutes to create cylinder blocks.

// To verify.

/dev: gpart show da1

// This reveals that the bulk of the USB is freebsd-ufs and a tiny part is reserved for adminitrative purposes, so to speak.

// Just to be sure:-

/dev: gpart show da1

// This gives the same information as /dev: gpart show da1.

2. MOUNTING.
   // To ascertain if this USB was mounted:-

/dev: df

// This USB did not appear, so I removed it from the computer, which let me know that the guest had departed.

// I then attached the USB to the computer again, and it was recognised as an unmounted guest, so to speak.

// Then:-

/dev: cd /

/: mount -t ufs dev/da1 media/USB

// And the message spat back

No such file    dev/da1

/: mount -t freebsd-ufs dev/da1 media/USB

// And the message spat back

No such file    dev/da1

// I then tried

/: mount -t freebsd-ufs dev/da1p1 media/USB

// And the message spat back

No such file    dev/da1p1

// I then tried

/: mount -t ufs dev/da1p1 media/USB

// And the message spat back

No such file    dev/da1p1

// Because ufs is the default, I then tried

/: mount dev/da1 media/USB

// And the message spat back

No such file    dev/da1

// I then made the final attempt

/: mount dev/da1p1 media/USB

// And the message spat back

No such file    dev/da1p1

3. SCREAMING.
   Having devoted the entire day to hunting for a solution, man ages, FreeBSD Handbook, this site, and other sites, I give up.

I have never had this kind of trouble in ten years of mounting ufs USB's.

Perhaps one of you kind souls will know what may be wrong.

Comment: I am already in /

Comment: Are you running FreeBSD as a VM guest? I have run through your steps using my 12.1 machine and it all works as expected.

Comment: No VM. Straight native FreeBSD. I believe that I am mounting the disc improperly; the arguments may be wrong in mount -t or something. I appreciate your telling me that the commands for formatting work; that is what I suspected. Now, all that remains is to determine what the correct flavour of mount may be. Again, the USB is formatted in ufs.

Comment: The correct argument is `-t ufs` - but that's the default and can be omitted. I used `mount /dev/da0p1 /media`

Comment: I used to do this all the time but haven't needed to for quite a while. You shouldn't be having any trouble with this at all but my answer will have to wait till I can get a usb to try it.

Comment: SOLVED! Mr. Richard Smith, you are right, and Rob, I used to mount these all the time, too! mount -t ufs and so on didn't work for me! Odd. But you are right. I finally remembered; ufs is default and so no need to specify. From /root, the command mount /dev/da1p1 media/USB works like a top for me. For other situations, the da1p1 may appear in one of several variants (da0, da0p1, da1, da1p1, and others) , depending on the formatting of the USB. Many thanks to all!

Comment: If you have found a solution, consider adding it as an answer. This would potentially benefit others with the same or similar issues. You may later "accept" your own answer, which would mark the issue as resolved. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer